Relationship between Beta distribution and its inverse
I am attempting to transform a real world density into risk-neutral density via calibration through the beta distribution.
Calibration in this context is transforming the rw density into the rn density by applying the beta distribution onto the rw cdf in a way that maximises the fit. So I have a rn cdf and rw cdf, and I want to obtain the parameters of the beta distribution that would transform the rw cdf into a new cdf that best matches the rn cdf.
Say I obtain the distribution that does the above transformation. Would the inverse of this beta distribution = the beta distribution that is obtained when transforming risk-neutral into real-world aka the opposite approach to the initial? If not, why?
Approach is outlined on this paper for reference:
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2093397

Can you edit your question to describe precisely what you mean by "calibration through the beta distribution"? Do you mean to use a beta distribution PDF as a Radon-Nikodym derivative? And what do you mean by "inverse" of a distribution? The inverse of its CDF?

Thank you for your reply Wei. I have attached the paper that outlines the approach I was referring to. And correct, the inverse of the CDF.

Thanks, but I think you will get more traction here if you put all relevant details in your question to make it self-contained, rather than having responders search through a 39-page paper for them. E.g. what precisely you mean by "calibration".

Thank you for clarifying! I have edited my question, hopefully it helps make my question clearer

So if I understand correctly, you have a "real-world" CDF $F$. Then you calibrate a beta CDF $B$ to give you a "risk-neutral" CDF $G$ with $G(x) = B(F(x))$.
Then yes, it is the case that $F(x)=B^{-1}(G(x))$.
Note that this only holds for the calibrated risk-neutral measure, not the "true" risk-neutral measure that you were fitting to.

Thanks Wei! So if I were to instead calibrate F(x)=B(G(x)), would B in this case be = B^-1 from the above?

Yes that's right, but in your case, $B$ wouldn't in general be a beta CDF (AFAIK).
